# What's wrong in this merge sort code that it runs for horribly long time?

Tags: java, mergesort

So, the algorithm below works perfectly fine, for input sizes - 10,20,30
Input size - 35 time lag is visible in output
Input size - 40 You will be waiting a while
Anything above 40 - doesn't complete sorting.

```
public class TestSorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start, end;

        Comparable[] numbers = generateRandom(45);
        Comparable[] temp;

        temp = Arrays.copyOf(numbers,numbers.length);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("                  M E R G E   S O R T");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Initial: " + Arrays.asList(temp));
        start = System.nanoTime();
        Merge.sort(temp);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Final  : " + Arrays.asList(temp));
        System.out.println("Total Runtime: " + (end-start));


    }

    private static Comparable[] generateRandom(int size) {
        Comparable[] data = new Comparable[size];

        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0 ;i<size;i++)
            data[i] = random.nextInt(100);

        return data;
    }
}
```

Merge.java

```
public class Merge {

    public static boolean lessThan(Comparable x, Comparable y) {
       return x.compareTo(y)<0;
    }

    public static void sort(Comparable[] data) {
        sort(data,0,data.length-1);
    }


    private static void sort(Comparable[] data,int low,int high) {
        if(high<=low) return;

        int mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        sort(data,0,mid);
        sort(data,mid+1,high);
        merge(data,low,mid,high);
    }

    private static void merge(Comparable[] data, int low, int mid, int high) {

        Comparable[] X = new Comparable[mid-low+1]
        Comparable[] Y = new Comparable[high-mid];

        for(int i=0;i<X.length;i++) X[i] = data[low+i];
        for(int i=0;i<Y.length;i++) Y[i] = data[mid+1+i];

        int start1 = 0, start2 = 0;
        while(start1<X.length && start2<Y.length) {
            if(lessThan(X[start1],Y[start2])) data[low++] = X[start1++];
            else data[low++] = Y[start2++];
        }

        while (start1 < X.length) data[low++] = X[start1++];
        while (start2 < Y.length) data[low++] = Y[start2++];
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?
Is it the extra local array creations that's making it go slow?

Comment: When you don't understand what your code is doing, then you should add trace prints to make it possible to observe what happens. Nothing in there (creating that random data and merge sorting it) should require any noticeable amount of time. Probably one of your loops goes crazy. Print what you are doing, and you will quickly see. That is called debugging, and learning how to do that is actually half of what programming is about.

Comment: I do have the trace statements and debug, but to not make this code any longer than it is, and not to clutter people's view who wants to answer genuinely, I filtered them out and not decided to include in here.

Comment: And maybe you read my comment again. The core point is that sorting less than 50 elements should not take any time. If it does, as you said, then your code is not working. Perfectly working merge sort deals with millions of entries. And I didn't say you have to include trace prints here. You are the one who says "I don't understand what happens". If giving you guidance how to approach such situations isn't constructive, sorry, then I am out of my wits. We do not debug your code for you.

Comment: @GhostCat: Thanks mate! Re-reading what you meant to say, I get it! debugging is important and an excellent skill to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive call

```
sort(data,0,mid);
```

should actually be

```
sort(data,low,mid);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Can you explain a bit what went wrong?

Comment: change it back and add some debug output that prints low and high - you will immediately see ...

Comment: thank you very much! I got where I was going wrong. The 0 created problem in the right half of recursion.